# How do you add all untracked files in svn? Something like git add -i?

Tags: svn, version-control

I've been using this long command:

```
svn st | awk '/\?/ {print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

Similarly, to svn rm files I accidentally deleted with normal rm with :

```
svn st | awk '/\!/ {print $2}' | xargs svn rm --force
```

I guess I can write a bash function to do these two, but I'd prefer an interactive add/rm like the one git has.

Comment: Note that your one liners break for untracked files with spaces in their name

Comment: Use `svn st | grep '^?' | sed 's/^[? ]*/"/' | sed 's/$/"/' | xargs svn add` instead which doesn't suffer from the whitespace problem

Answer (score 10):

This adds all svn-untracked and -unversioned files in the current directory, recursing through all subdirectories:

```
svn add --force ./*
```

Works for me in MacOS 10.6+ and Ubuntu 10+, with svn 1.6+. This does not provide any per-file, user-interactivity; I don't know how to do that.

This will also add svn-ignored files, for better or worse.

Comment: That will also add ignored files, which is probably not what most people want.

Comment: @IanDunn thanks, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

there's an easier line...

```
svn add `svn status | grep ?`
```

then you can set it up as an alias in ~/.bashrc such as

```
alias svn-addi='svn add `svn status | grep ?`'
```

Comment: I ended up doing this: for a in `svn status | grep ? | nawk '{print $2}'`; do svn add $a; done

Answer (score 6):

I use a generalization of the command line that you run, called `svnapply.sh`. I did not write it, but I don't remember where I found it. Hopefully, the original author will forgive me for reposting it here:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Applies arbitrary commands to any svn status. e.g.
#
# Delete all non-svn files (escape the ? from the shell):
# svnapply \? rm
#
# List all conflicted files:
# svnapply C ls -l

APPLY=$1
shift

svn st | egrep "^\\${APPLY}[ ]+" | \
sed -e "s|^\\${APPLY}[ ]*||" | \
sed -e "s|\\\\|/|g" | \
xargs -i "$@" '{}'
```

Per the comments, the script allows you to run arbitrary commands against all files with the same status.

Update:

It would not be too difficult to write a script that takes a file path as an argument and prompts the user for add/delete and then does the appropriate thing for that file. Chaining that together with the above script would get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068506/svn-add-interactive) which contains a [nice Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068506/svn-add-interactive/1321101#1321101) that gives you the option to add, ignore or skip new files. I've tried it and it worked for me. No GUI needed, only Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GUI that can show you all the untracked files, then select all and add.  Any decent SVN gui should provide this functionality.

That said, be careful you really want all those files.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN has the option of showing unversioned files in the Commit and Show Changes dialogs. You can right click a file to 'Add' it or to mark it as ignored.

If you are using Visual Studio:
The latest stable version of AnkhSVN has a similar command, but in most cases it only shows the files you should add. (The project provides a list of files to version to the SCC provider; other files are ignored automatically)

Comment: If you're in the TortoiseSVN commit dialog you can be even lazier. TortoiseSVN will automatically add any non-versioned files that you have checked in the dialog when you commit.