# How can I remove a substring of a string in a shell script?

Tags: string, shell, sed, scripting

I have a file with a list of words like:

```
FIRST_WORD abc
FIRST_WORD(1) bcd
FIRST_WORD(2) def
SECOND_WORD gh
THIRD_WORD jiu
THIRD_WORD(1) lom
...
```

and I want to remove the `(i)`, when it is present, to obtain:

```
FIRST_WORD abc
FIRST_WORD bcd
FIRST_WORD def
SECOND_WORD gh
THIRD_WORD jiu
THIRD_WORD lom
...
```

Comment: The question title doesn't match the example!?

Comment: So if `(i)` appears elsewhere it should not be replaced, or will it never appear other than as per examples?

Comment: @ChrisSeymour Since OP hasn’t responded for a long time, I updated the question title. Please consider removing your comment and updating [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194320/711006) (the best one IMO) to mention that.

Answer (score 17):

You can get it:

```
test="123456"
echo ${test:3}
```

Output:

```
456
```

Comment: test="123456 abc"
echo ${test:3} gives as output 456 abc.
I want to obtain 123 abc

Comment: @user1835630 that is a different problem from both the title and the example? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: then try: `echo ${test:0:3}` and you will get `123`

Comment: it's giving me bad substitution

Answer (score 3):

Global replacement of all digits strings found inside parenthesis using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/([0-9]\+)//g' file
FIRST_WORD abc
FIRST_WORD bcd
FIRST_WORD def
SECOND_WORD gh
THIRD_WORD jiu
THIRD_WORD lom

# Save the changes back to the file  
$ sed -i 's/([0-9]\+)//g' file
```

---

Removing the first 3 characters using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^...//' file
ST_WORD abc
ST_WORD(1) bcd
ST_WORD(2) def
OND_WORD gh
RD_WORD jiu
RD_WORD(1) lom
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
sed 's/([0-9])//g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '$!N;s/^((\S+).*\n\2)\([^)]*\)/\1/;P;D' file
```

However it might be overkill, if:

```
sed 's/([0-9]\+)//' file
```

is suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure bash implementation:

```
while read -r a b; do
    echo "${a%(*)}" "$b"
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally go with `sed` for replacing in files as it is built specifically for that, but in case someone needs to do this operation inside a longer bash script, you can also use bash's search and replace syntax `${var//search/replace}`.

```bash
while read -r line; do
  echo "${line//(*)/}"
done < ./in.txt
```