# Adding all files under a folder that have not been added in subversion?

Tags: svn

I have a folder, called "files". It's already in the repository. Now, new files are constantly added to this folder and it's subfolder. What command can I type to add all the files that have not yet been added. This does NOT work:

```
svn add files
```

It says

> svn: warning: 'files' is already under version control

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071857/how-do-i-svn-add-all-unversioned-files-to-svn

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
svn add files/*
```

or:

```
svn add --force files
```

(taken from [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html))

Comment: 5 years later, you helped me also! Thanks, the --force was what I needed to add the files changed in subfolders of subfolders...

Answer (score 14):

If you'd like to add all files in a folder, including all subfolders, this is a really handy script:

```
svn status | awk '{if ($1 == "?") print $2 }' | xargs svn add
```

Answer (score 3):

#### If your all directories are not adding recursively. Then check this.

**recursive adding is default property**. You can see in [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html).

Issue can be in your ignore list or global properties.

I got solution [google issue tracker](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/GR52pcbOq58)

- Right click in your repo in window. Select `TortoiseSVN > Properties`.
- See if you don't have a property `svn:global-ignores with a value of *`
- If you have property with `star(*)` then it will ignore recursive adding. So remove this property.

This guy [also explained](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/GR52pcbOq58/DSBEQyU7FCwJ) why this property added in my project.

The most like way that it got there is that someone right-clicked a file without any extension and selected TortoiseSVN -> SVN Ignore -> * (recursively), and then committed this.

> You can check the log to see who committed that property change, find
> out what they were actually trying to do, and ask them to be more
> careful in future. :)