# "svn add *" adds even those files which are ignored

Tags: svn, ignore

I am using svn add * to add files to the svn, and it adds the config file which is for sure added to ignore.

```
lyuba@lyuba-laptop:/workspace/project$ svn propget svn:ignore
.sass-cache
config.js
```

What can cause the problem?

Comment: The problem was not finally resolved and I convinced my team to switch to git. Very happy about it!

Answer (score 11):

Super old Question but I ran into this issue just now and the solution I found is not listed here. Adrian Smith's answer is on the right track. I assume the docs and SVN itself have seen many updates in 5 years. Here is what I found in the [SVN docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)

> Even if `svn:ignore` is set, you may run into problems if you use shell wildcards in a command. Shell wildcards are expanded into an explicit list of targets before Subversion operates on them, so running `svn SUBCOMMAND *` is just like running `svn SUBCOMMAND file1 file2 file3 …`. In the case of the `svn add` command, this has an effect similar to passing the `--no-ignore` option. So instead of using a wildcard, use `svn add --force .` to do a bulk scheduling of unversioned things for addition. The explicit target will ensure that the current directory isn't overlooked because of being already under version control, and the `--force` option will cause Subversion to crawl through that directory, adding unversioned files while still honoring the `svn:ignore` property and `global-ignores` runtime configuration variable. Be sure to also provide the `--depth files` option to the `svn add` command if you don't want a fully recursive crawl for things to add.

The short version is use `svn add --force .` This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 10):

In UNIX and Linux, if you say

```
svn add *
```

Then the shell will expand all the files in the directory and the program will see the same as if you'd typed

```
svn add file-a.txt file-b.txt file-c.txt
```

etc. This means that the Subversion command thinks you've explicitly listed the file for adding. In this case, it'll add it, even though the `svn:ignore` property might be set.

From the  [documentation of `svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) (my emphasis):

> Subversion uses the ignore patterns to determine which files should not be swept into the version control system as part of a **larger recursive addition** or import operation.

Comment: How can I make svn add all files, created recently, and keep ignore simultaneously?

Comment: If I added some files, which are located not in ., but rather in, for example, scss/pages/_comparison.scss, then the command you suggested doesn't add them. Instead it says svn: warning: '.' is already under version control

Comment: I have the same problem. The issue is that you cannot set what files to ignore, before you add the dir to svn. however, once added with `add . -depth empty` (and the `svn:ignore` patterns are set), you cannot use `add . --depth infinity`

Answer (score 2):

Use this command instead of `svn add --force *` :

```
svn add --force ./
```

In this case svn itself parse all files in directory and it considers the ignored files, but when you use *, you explicitly tell svn to add all files.

Answer (score 1):

I found that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071857/how-do-i-svn-add-all-unversioned-files-to-svn) contains a very good solution. As the answer is not actually answering the question, I do not think it is duplicate.
In brief use the power of unix tools (works with cygwin on windows):

`svn status | grep '?' | sed 's/^.* /svn add /' | bash`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried committing the config.js to see if it is really ignored?  I think if you specifically tell svn to add a file to version control, it'll over ride the ignore.

Comment: Trying to commit is not the way to find out btw, if it's added it will be committed. svn:ignore is to prevent it from being added.