# Powershell: SVN revert for all files matching a given pattern

Tags: svn, powershell, windows-7

I accidentally added dozens of backup files to SVN and would like to recursively revert all files matching a given pattern (*.~sql)

On UNIX, I'd simply use a

```
svn revert `svn status .|grep "~sql$"|awk '{print $2}'`
```

which is a variation of one of the answers to [How do I 'svn add' all unversioned files to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071857/how-do-i-svn-add-all-unversioned-files-to-svn)

Using Powershell, I came up with

```
svn status|findstr "~sql" | %{ $_.Split('`t')[1]; }
```

but this seems to cut of the first characters of the filenames 
(e.g. I get ch_sys.~sql instead of scratch_sys.~sql).

What am I missing here? Or is there a more Powershellish way of doing this?

Comment: Powershell way of doing something is called POSH and not Powershellish :)

Comment: manojlds, that sounds kinda stupid, though ;-) (at least I could never get used to calling PowerShell PoSh – besides, »posh« doesn't really sound that powerful :-P)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use

```
$_.Split("`t")
```

as a quick fix for your code because currently you have a string containing `` `t `` instead of a string containing a tab because single-quoted strings don't allow escape sequences (except `""`). `string.Split` gets a `char[]` as argument and splits at any of the characters you passed, so in this case it splits on a grave accent and `t`.

But you are right, that's not really a PowerShell-y way of doing this. First of all, you're using `findstr` which has plenty of PowerShell equivalents, e.g.

```
svn status | where { $_ -match '~sql' }
(svn status) -match '~sql'
```

When working with SVN from PowerShell you have another option, though. Most SVN commands can output XML which is a lot more robust to handle than text output, usually.

```
([xml](svn status --xml)).status.target.entry |
  select -exp path |
  where {$_ -match '~sql'} |
  foreach { svn revert $_ }
```

Whether that's prettier is probably debatable, but I prefer working with structured data when possible.

However,

```
svn revert -R *~sql*
```

should work, too, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the " vs ' problem - I wasn't aware of that. When I try your last solution (svn status --xml) ..., I get an error svn: E205001: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided

Comment: That's weird. But the code wasn't correct so far anyway. Still, the `revert` call *should* work.

Comment: (svn status --xml).status apparently doesn't return anything; I'm using Powershell V1, might this be the cause for the problem?

Comment: Argh, I forgot the cast. The supposedly nicer snippet is getting increasingly uglier.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. FYI, the svn revert -R *~sql* doesn't work, since it's not reverting recursively (even if quoting the *~sql* to prevent the shell from expanding the wildcards).

Comment: The shell won't expand wildcards on Windows, but it could be that SVN is replicating the Unix behaviour by only expanding wildcards with respect to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Select-String, alias sls you can also use regex for matching.

```
([xml](svn status --xml)).status.target.entry.path | sls ".+sql" | %{svn revert $_}
```

(n.b. $_ is a matchinfo that gets converted into a string)